# Cloudkit dashboard : Error fetching subscriptions. Expected this response but could not parse it: HTTP 200

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

if anyone could help I am beyond frustrated with an issue being experienced with Appple's cloud kit dashboard

I keep receiving the following error after creating a subscription to the public database:

Expected this response but could not parse it: HTTP 200, text: {"subscriptions":[{"type":"query","subscriptionId":"E38D14D7-4864-45E7-943C-5BF0307B16E4","query":{"recordType":"Documents","filters":[{"fieldName":"AssetName","fieldValue":{"type":"stringType","value":""},"type":"NOT_EQUALS"}]},"firesOn":["CREATE"],"firesOnce":false,"zone":

the code used to create the subscription is as follows:

```
      let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "AssetName != %@", "")
       
      let subscription = CKQuerySubscription(recordType: "Documents", predicate: predicate, options: .firesOnRecordCreation)

      let notification = CKSubscription.NotificationInfo()
    notification.soundName = "default"
    notification.title = "Title"
    notification.titleLocalizationArgs = ["AssetName"]
    notification.titleLocalizationKey = "AssetName"
    notification.subtitle = "Subtitle"
    notification.subtitleLocalizationArgs = ["AssetName"]
    notification.alertBody = "New document created."
    notification.alertLocalizationArgs = ["AssetName"]
    
    subscription.notificationInfo = notification

    CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase.save(subscription) { result, error in
           if error != nil {
               print(error!.localizedDescription)
           } else {
               print(subscription)
           }
       }
```

Any assistance, would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this issue has been happening for lots of people. It' most likely a server-side error. Check [this link](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/689013).

Comment: Thanx, when i get a chance i'll check on this and let you guys know

Comment: No worries, it should all be fixed now :)

Answer (score 0):

I was running into this issue as well. Everything is working now though. The Cloudkit dashboard has some aesthetic changes so I'm assuming a fix was pushed out along with that latest update.